# Deploy rails app for different environments in one virtual host instance with Phusion Passenger

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3.2, passenger

I had the rails app deploy to a virtual host with IP, for example, 10.10.10.10. By default, Phusion Passenger run the app in production environment. The nginx config was:

```
server {
        listen       80;
        server_name  10.10.10.10;
        rails_env    production;
        root         /root/www/production/public;
        passenger_enabled on;
 }
```

Now I want to deploy the app in test environment in the same host. Wonder if I can do something like

```
server {
            listen       80;
            server_name  TEST_SERVER_NAME;
            rails_env    test;
            root         /root/www/test/public;
            passenger_enabled on;
     }
```

What should be the TEST_SERVER_NAME? My host instance only has one IP.

Actually I am confused about the server_name. Is it necessary to match with the host instance? But saw examples in the documentation that can be bar.com and far.com in the same time. If it can be a random name, could I use google.com then everyone goes to google.com will be served by my site? Of course I can't. How does the server_name work then?

Answer (score 0):

nginx uses the `server_name` directive to decide which server should process an incoming request.  So, it's not just any random name and nginx will try to match each incoming request with the servers defined in the config.

Here's the [official doc](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/request_processing.html) if you need more information.